# How do I implement scientific experiment to derive a equation called Gerber Line?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, stresses, machining, fatigue

How do I implement scientific experiment to derive a equation relevant to subject of stress and fatigue called Gerber Line equation?

[image]

May you also provide some historical context to that?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goodman_relation